# php Uncaught Error: Class 'BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyFactory' not found

Tags: php, composer-php

im trying to add a library to my php. I already downloaded all the files from composer but a fatal error happended. here is my code :

```
  require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
      use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Bitcoin;
      use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Address\AddressCreator;
      use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyFactory;
      use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\KeyToScript\Factory\P2pkhScriptDataFactory; 

        //Rest of my code

ERROR 1 -> Uncaught Error: Class 'BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyFactory' not found 
ERROR 2 -> Class 'BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyFactory' not found
```

Comment: Can you share your project directory structure

Comment: run **composer dump-autoload** , and look if the error still there

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that namespace be `BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\Factory\PrivateKeyFactory`?

See here https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php/blob/1.0/src/Key/Factory/PrivateKeyFactory.php#L5